# LAMP vhost still points to www/html

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, lamp

I've created the following virtual host file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/lion.dev`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lion.dev
    ServerName lion.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/lion.dev
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/lion.dev/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/lion.dev/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/lion.dev/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that it is actually pointing to the `/www/html` folder when I visit `lion.dev` in my browser.

What am I missing and why isn't this working?

Comment: Did you restart apache after your change?

Comment: Yeah I restarted apache. I figured out I had to also create a link in the `sites-enabled` folder. It is working now.

Comment: So either delete or answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by uninstalling Ubuntu and re-installing Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Did you uncomment load virtual host in httpd.conf file?
That is usally commented and the module wont be loaded, just remove //before virtual host part.
My apologies I saw late that you resolved the issue.